# No Model And View found in Controller Test

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller, dispatcher

I have a test class that looks like this
  I found out that the test when i use @WebMvcTest Does not recognize the url for some reason.Any help would suffice please .
After debugging i get that DefaultRequestBuilder =Null, DefaultRequestMatcher size=0

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc()
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest({ShoppingCartController.class, HomeController.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfig.class})
public class ShoppingCartControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private CartItemService cartItemService;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void showLoginPage() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)

                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        )
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("classActiveLogin"))
                .andReturn();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "V", authorities = {"USER"})
    public void addItemToShoppingCart() throws Exception {
        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();
        String qty = "2";

        Book book = new Book();
        User user = new User();
        book.setId(1L);
        book.getId();

        cartItem.setBook(book);
        when(userService.findByUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(user);


        when(bookService.findOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(book);

        when(cartItemService.addBookToCartItem(book, user, Integer.parseInt(qty))).thenReturn(cartItem);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String bookAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(book);
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/shoppingCart/addItem")
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        .param("book", bookAsString)
                        .param("qty", qty))
                .andReturn();
    }



    @Configuration
    @Import({PropertyTestConfiguration.class, SecurityUtility.class})
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }

}
```

Only the test addItemToShoppingcCart passes , the other three have the same error as shown below , It is definitely not importing everything I need but I cant figure out what exactly it is.

java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found

```
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:35)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:65)
I don't understand why I t cant find models and views but when I use @
```

SpringBootTest and EasyMock everything passes ? what can I do ?

These are my controllers

```
 @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("classActiveLogin", true);
        return "Myaccount";
    }

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @RequestMapping("/addItem")
    public String addItem(
            @ModelAttribute("book") Book book,
            @ModelAttribute("qty") String qty,
            Model model, Principal principal
    ) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());


        try {
            book = bookService.findOne(book.getId());

            if (Integer.parseInt(qty) > book.getInStockNumber()) {
                model.addAttribute("notEnoughStock", true);
                return "forward:/bookDetail?id=" + book.getId();
            }

            CartItem cartItem = cartItemService.addBookToCartItem(book, user, Integer.parseInt(qty));
            model.addAttribute("addBookSuccess", true);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

        return "forward:/bookDetail?id=" + book.getId();
    }
```

I have two controllers i am testing

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private MailConstructor mailConstructor;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("classActiveLogin", true);
        return "Myaccount";
    }
```

And Second one which has Class level Mapping

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shoppingCart")
public class ShoppingCartController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    // autowired services here

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @RequestMapping("/addItem")
    public String addItem(
            @ModelAttribute("book") Book book,
            @ModelAttribute("qty") String qty,
            Model model, Principal principal
    ) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());


        try {
            book = bookService.findOne(book.getId());

            if (Integer.parseInt(qty) > book.getInStockNumber()) {
                model.addAttribute("notEnoughStock", true);
                return "forward:/bookDetail?id=" + book.getId();
            }

            CartItem cartItem = cartItemService.addBookToCartItem(book, user, Integer.parseInt(qty));
            model.addAttribute("addBookSuccess", true);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

        return "forward:/bookDetail?id=" + book.getId();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: i have added the controller code  thank you  @AmitKBist

Comment: is there any @RequestMapping at the controller class level?

Comment: Yes there is and I posted the controllers @Amin K Bist

Comment: You have not pasted complete controller class. I can see only method level @RequestMapping, is there any class level RequestMapping annotation?

Comment: No my controller is is -@Controller  class  HomeController {}. And @Controller class ShoppingCartControler @RequestMapping(“/shopping cart”)

Comment: Edit ur qs to add controller class code, it seems u have /shopping cart annotation on the controller class. If yes, then u need to make ur test method call get(/shopping cart/login)

Comment: @AmitKBist check i have posted the class , login is in a different class which has no class level mapping while addItem is in a class with a class level mapping , Thank you for your assist , i have been on this for days

Comment: @Amit K Bist Have u seen my update , no suggestions?